# SFINAE inside concept template argument

Tags: c++, sfinae, c++20, c++-concepts

Does SFINAE work inside a concept argument? (maybe it's not called SFINAE here). Example:

```
template <class F>
    requires
        std::invocable<F, int> && // <-- is this needed?
        (!std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<F, int>, void>)
auto foo(F f, int a) -> int
```

Is the above `std::invocable<F, int>` required?

If we omit it like so:

```
template <class F>
    requires (!std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<F, int>, void>)
auto foo(F f, int a) -> int
```

Is this version well-formed even if `std::invoke_result_t<F, int>` is not (i.e. if it is not invocable) or is it UB/ill formed, ndr?

```
foo(11, 24);
// std::invoke_result_t<int, int> does not exist,
// is the second variant the one without `std::invocable<F, int>` ok in this case?
```

---

gcc seems to behave without it: https://godbolt.org/z/SEH94-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFINAE still works with constraints.

A substitution failure results in an atomic constraint (such as `(!std::same_as<std::invoke_result_t<F, int>, void>)`)  being deemed as not satisfied

> **[temp.constr.atomic]**
>
> [3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.atomic#3) To determine if an atomic constraint is satisfied, the
>   parameter mapping and template arguments are first substituted into
>   its expression. If substitution results in an invalid type or
>   expression, the constraint is not satisfied. Otherwise, the
>   lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is performed if necessary, and E shall be
>   a constant expression of type bool. The constraint is satisfied if and
>   only if evaluation of E results in true. If, at different points in
>   the program, the satisfaction result is different for identical atomic
>   constraints and template arguments, the program is ill-formed, no
>   diagnostic required. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> concept C =
>   sizeof(T) == 4 && !true;      // requires atomic constraints sizeof(T) == 4 and !true
>
> template<typename T> struct S {
>   constexpr operator bool() const { return true; }
> };
>
> template<typename T> requires (S<T>{})
> void f(T);                      // #1
> void f(int);                    // #2
>
> void g() {
>   f(0);                         // error: expression S<int>{} does not have type bool
> }                               // while checking satisfaction of deduced arguments of #1;
>                                 // call is ill-formed even though #2 is a better match
> ```
>
> — end example ]

During template argument deduction, an unsatisfied constraint causes the deduction process to be unsuccessful

> **[temp.deduct]**
>
> [5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#5) ... If the function template has associated constraints
>   ([temp.constr.decl]), those constraints are checked for satisfaction
>   ([temp.constr.constr]). If the constraints are not satisfied, type
>   deduction fails.

The age old SFINAE specification still applies during overload resolution, so when substitution fails, the overload is not considered.

> **[temp.over]**
>
> [1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over#1) ... If, for a given function template, argument deduction fails
>   or the synthesized function template specialization would be
>   ill-formed, no such function is added to the set of candidate
>   functions for that template ...

So all in all, GCC behaves correctly, as one should expect.