# Nested dependent names are not evaluated in template for concept

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

(Originally separated from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63654388/does-typename-have-to-be-specfied-inside-template).)

In the following code snippet,

```
#include <concepts>

template<
    typename T,
    typename value_type = typename T::value_type
>
concept check_type = std::default_initializable<T>;

struct Foo {};

template<check_type T>
void func(T t) {}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    func(foo);
}
```

`struct Foo` does not contain the type alias `value_type` but it compiles without an error with GCC.

See the [result tested on the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/W15Eoj).

However, with Clang, it reports the following error message:

```
❯ clang++ -std=c++20 asdf.cpp
asdf.cpp:17:5: error: no matching function for call to 'func'
    func(foo);
    ^~~~
asdf.cpp:12:6: note: candidate template ignored: constraints not satisfied [with T = Foo]
void func(T t) {}
     ^
asdf.cpp:5:39: note: because substituted constraint expression is ill-formed: no type named 'value_type' in 'Foo'
    typename value_type = typename T::value_type
                                      ^
1 error generated.
```

Also see the [result tested on the compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/j55T5c).

Is this a bug?

Comment: This may be worth a CWG issue. If the substitution failure is inside the constraint *expression*, [then the constraint is not satisfied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847693/sfinae-inside-concept-template-argument). But as far as I can see, nothing is mentioned about substitution failure inside the constraint's own template parameter list. I think GCC is wrong anyway to consider the constraint satisfied. Clang doesn't consider it satisfied. But an argument can be made that this should be a hard error, because the constraint can surely be re-written to not do SFINAE within SFINAE.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Given the link you gave, GCC should have raised error, if the constraint for a template parameter yields false. Anyway, I'm reporting this bug.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Besides, what's CWG? I googled it, and it seems like a working draft (consensus) driven by the C++ community.

Comment: You misunderstood. The link I shared is about the behavior when the **expression** contains the problem, not the parameter list. GCC behaves correctly in the expression case as far as I'm aware (unless there was a regression). Your example **is not covered by the standard** to the best of my scrutiny. That's why an issue could potentially be raised for the Core Working Group (responsible for the core language, as part of ISO WG21).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica The concept doesn't use `value_type` at all, so it's not part of the parameter mappings after normalization. I think GCC is correct?

Comment: @T.C. - IDK, the normative wording is kinda confusing me. But if we go by the example http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.atomic#2.example-1 - Then it claims we get the atomic constraint `Atomic<N>` and mapping `N -> 2 * M + 1`. But `Atomic` doesn't use `N`, so it seems like a parameter doesn't need to be used to be mapped. And so the unnamed parameter in the OP should still get mapped, and be ill-formed somehow when `value_type` isn't present. But again, I'm kinda confused by this, so I could be way off.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica In that example, `Atomic` is a variable template so we don't normalize into it.

Comment: @T.C. - Okay, then that clarifies the example for me, thanks. But I can't really say that GCC's behavior falls inline with my expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is correct under the current wording.

Per [[temp.deduct]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#5.sentence-6), satisfaction checking is done on the *associated constraints* of the function template:

> If the function template has associated constraints ([temp.constr.decl]), those constraints are checked for satisfaction ([temp.constr.constr]).

[[temp.constr.decl]/3.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.decl#3.2) specifies that the associated constraint is based on the normal form:

> A declaration's associated constraints are defined as follows:
>
> - ...
> - Otherwise, if there is a single introduced
>   *constraint-expression*, the associated constraints are the normal form
>   of that expression.

Since `check_type` is a concept, it is transparent to normalization ([[temp.constr.normal]/1.4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.normal#1.4)), and since the second template parameter of `check_type` is not used in its definition, that parameter does not appear in the normal form of the constraint expression. Therefore, the validity (or lack thereof) of `T::value_type` has no effect on satisfaction checking.

If you want the concept to check for `value_type`, it is more expressive (not to mention correct) to just check for `value_type` directly:

```
template <typename T>
concept check_type = std::default_initializable<T> && requires { typename T::value_type; };
```

Comment: I initially wanted to declare an alias and do substitution check at the same time, because it is not possible to declare a type alias inside the `requires` clause. I hope the `concept`'s template parameter to behave consistently regardless of compilers. Maybe I can expect this gets discussed as part of CWG.

Comment: @PHD: It's not CWG's responsibility to fix compiler bugs. And even if CWG changes the standard, it would likely be to make using `check_type` in this way a *compile error* (just as it would be if you had tried to do `check_type<int, int::value_type>`), not to make it a de-facto part of the `requires` clause. If you want something in the `requires` clause, then put it there.